# Is there a lower bound to the time for which an SQS MessageID is unique?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

[The documentation for SQS Messages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_Message.html) says this about `MessageID`s:

> [It is a] unique identifier for the message. A MessageId is considered unique across all AWS accounts for an extended period of time.

Is there a lower bound to the amount of time that constitutes "an extended period of time"?

Comment: I definitely don't have a proper answer, but message ID's have a max length of 100 chars, providing a pretty massive keyspace. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-queue-message-identifiers.html